# What are the fonts used in standard UITableVIew cell UILabel & UITextFiled?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uitextfield, uifont

Background:  I am creating a custom `UITableViewCell` and adding some views with text and want to match the font/size/colour that apple uses for standard controls

Questions:  what are the fonts/sizes used, in say the iPhone / Settings / Safari / 1st tableviewcell for:

A) title text, ie "search engine" in my example
B) current value blueish text, "google" for my example

That is if was creating the `UILabel` and `UITextField` eqivalents how would I see their fonts to look the same?

Comment: Apple's favorite font is Helvetica. The color you should be able to get with a color picker when taking a screenshot.

Comment: Ok - guess I was fishing for whether there might be something like UISystemFontForTableCellContent, or something lime that.

Comment: Yes, there is UIFont systemFontWithSize: - but I thought you were after the name of the font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to display it I would have thought, when you have a UITableViewCell*

```
NSLog(@"Cell font is %@", cell.textLabel.font);
```

I think it's either (not sure about the sizes)

```
[UIFont systemFontWithSize:]
[UIFont boldSystemFontWithSize:]
```

You could always make it future proof for your label by creating a default cell and setting your UILabel to the same font

```
label.font = cell.textLabel.font;
```

Comment: That's for the good tips. The current content font does seem to be a bit blue'ish it seems...

Comment: @Greg if all else fails, you could use the color picker MacOS X utility, hover it over the color you want and make a UIColor with RGB components.

Comment: Ok thanks - sounds like just do it manually then. Ie no predefined IOS constant for it....